# How to allow POST, PUT on IIS 8.x or higher for both localhost and remote

Tags: angularjs, http-status-code-405

I'm using Angular 1.5 for my $http.POST() and everything is working fine but I keep getting this error:

```
**GENERAL**
Request URL:http://localhost/ThingBlu/OmniGrow/js/json/logged-users.json
Request Method:POST
Status Code:405 Method Not Allowed
Remote Address:[::1]:80

**Response Headers**
Allow:GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, TRACE
Cache-Control:private
Content-Length:5448
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Sun, 11 Sep 2016 18:08:27 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET

**Request Headers**
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Authorization:Basic OWFjMTIwMTAtNjhmZC00YTY4LWIxMTQtMTI3NjcyYmRkMmNkOjRmOGJkMDg0LTY2NDQtNDVmMi1iNGI4LWI4OTgwNzgyMDkzZA==
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:305
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
Cookie:XDEBUG_SESSION=XDEBUG_ECLIPSE; ASPSESSIONIDQARBBSBC=LGJPEMMBPPMIKGAEMPOKDDKP; ASPSESSIONIDQAQBBRDC=HNLHMCECDLFMFBMOFMNFNNEA; ASPSESSIONIDSARCBSBD=DMGPJIECDOKINIEIIADELBOG; ASPSESSIONIDSCQBCQCD=HHHNEBHCACCJABGNFAMFHNAD; ASPSESSIONIDQATBARBD=KFNLJLHCMOECJOMCDDOFBINL; ASPSESSIONIDQCSABTAC=GDGJMOMCNPDBJAAOKJJHDDGH
DNT:1
Host:localhost
Origin:http://localhost
Referer:http://localhost/ThingBlu/OmniGrow/index.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.101 Safari/537.36
```

Here's the problem:

My WebConfig file has the following:

```
<modules>
    <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
</modules>
<handlers>
    <remove name="WebDAV" />
</handlers>
```

What's happening is whenever I step through the code, below, and hit a specific part, the above error occurs.

I'm writing to a local JSON file, WHICH I have successfully done when I worked for Frontier Communications.  It's VERY POSSIBLE much to the chagrin of most posts out there saying it's NOT.  I've done it and so does FRONTIER and T-MOBILE.  That being said, here's my ANGULAR code:

```
            /**
             * Then log the person in
             * @returns {object through promises}
             */
            ctrlLogin.fetchLogin = function () {

                //SUBMIT FORM
                $scope.submit = function () {
                    console.log('Submit Clicked');
                    //Encode Password if FormData is VALID
                    if ($scope.formData) {
                        formObj = {
                            uid: $scope.formData.myusername,
                            pwd: $scope.encode64($scope.formData.mypassword),
                            rmbr: $scope.formData.rememberme
                        };
                        //Login Data
                        loginData.svc.getLoginData(formObj).then(function (result) {
                            console.log("Login message: ", result);
                            //if success send the person through
                            if (result.data.message === "failure") {
                                console.log("ERROR: ", result.data.message);
                                $scope.changeRoute("/error");
                            } else {
                                console.log("SUCCESS: ", result.data);

                                //Get Path to JSON
                                $http.get(SVCURLS.data.loggedusers).then(function (data) {
                                    //SUCCESS so therefore pass ACTIVE = 1 for DASHBOARD as that's
                                    //where we're going next.
                                    if (appservice.appFuncs.saveToJson(result.data, 1)) {

                                        data.users = angular.toJson(result.data);
                                        //use $.param JQUERY function to serialize the data from JSON
                                        $scope.users = $.param(data.users);
                                        //CONFIG using HEADERS
                                        var config = HEADERS.tokenheaders;
                                        **//NOTE: THIS IS THE POINT AT WHICH THE 405 ERROR OCCURS**
                                        $http.post(SVCURLS.data.loggedusers, data.users, status, config)
                                                .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                                                    //SUCCESS CALBACK
                                                    $scope.PostDataResponse = data;
                                                    console.log("SUCCESS Writing to JSON FILE!");
                                                    window.location.href = "main-page.html";
                                                })
                                                .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                                                    //FAILURE CALLBACK
                                                    $scope.PostDataResponse = "DATA: " + data +
                                                            "<hr/>Status: " + status +
                                                            "<hr/>Headers: " + headers +
                                                            "<hr/>Config: " + config;
                                                    console.log("ERROR Writing to JSON FILE");
                                                    return deferred.reject(data ? data : '[NO DATA]');
                                                });
                                    } else {
                                        //ERROR show what happened
                                        console.log("ERROR: ", data);
                                        //Now flip the pages that the session has been
                                        //Created
                                        $scope.msg = "There was an error saving your information.";
                                        deferred.reject(data ? data : '[NO DATA]');
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    return "intial load";
                };
            };
            ctrlLogin.fetchLogin();
```

Help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It may be some other module (not WebDAV) that has conflicting verb filter. 
You may try to take a look at the content of the applicationHost.config file in the iis config folder. Suspicious modules are the ones that have same path and similar verbs. For example, if certain module X is disabled for your app in the IIS management console, but has matching path/verb filter defined in applicationHost.config, the handler for it will still be invoked as part of the request pipeline and the module will generate 405 status. 
Should you identified any conflicting modules you can remove them from the pipeline similar to how you did it for WebDAV in your web.config file.